# Text element not updating in arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to get a text element to input an address using the below code. It seems that the code picks up the right elements, is finding the text elements I want to change but isn't able to actually change the text element. I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
newmxd2 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(newmxd)
totalAddress = address + " " + street
for text in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(newmxd2, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    print(text.name)
    if text.name == "Address":
        test = text.text
        text.text = totalAddress
        print("Address has been changed from {0} to {1}.".format(test,totalAddress))
    if text.name == "WO":
        text.text = str(wo)
        print("Work order has been changed to {0}.".format(wo))
    else:
        print("Text and WO elements not found.")
```

Comment: What happens if you add this line after the `for` loop? `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()`

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the resulting map, unfortunately. I tried refreshing the view in ArcMap itself a few times too. The code picks out the correct text elements but "text.text = totalAddress" and "text.text = str(wo)" don't actually change what is inside the text box.

Comment: Are you exporting the MXD from arcpy or just looking at the MXD in ArcMap?

Comment: I'm running the code in Spyder outside of ArcMap and then opening the map document to see if the changes worked.

Comment: Are you saving the document using `newmxd2.save()`?

Comment: That was it. I knew it was something simple, I forgot all about that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, glad it worked. I am adding this as an asnwer so other people can refer to it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to note:

- If you are expecting the changes to be visible when you open the MXD file in ArcMap, save the MXD at the end of your script using the `newmxd2.save()` method.
- If you want to export the map (*e.g.* PNG of PDF) and want to see the changes in the exported file, you don't need to save the MXD as you are only using it as a template.
- If you are experimenting in ArcMap and want to see the changes right there without the need to run the script in Spyder and then open the document you can use the Python console that comes with ArcMap. However, instead of passing a string with the path of the MXD to the `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument()` function, pass the string `CURRENT` like this: `newmxd2 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')`. Then, after doing your changes, run `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` and see the changes you just made.